# Построение визуального дерева (TreeView)

Tags: delphi, gui

Есть список следующего содержания

```
Пост
Пост.Кладовая
Пост.Склад
Пост.Столовая
Пост.Столовая.Посудомоечная
Офис
Офис.Администраиция
```

Как этот список вывести в treeview? В смысле чтобы было

```
Пост
   |-Кладовая
   |-Склад
   |-Столовая
   |-Столовая
            |-Посудомоечная
Офис
   |-Администраиция
```

```pascal
type
   ...
   tvNodes: TTreeView;
 
procedure AddNode(tv: TTreeView; nt: string; pn: TTreeNode);
var
  nn: TTreeNode;
begin
  nn := tv.Items.AddChild(pn, nt);
end;
 
procedure BuildTree(tv: TTreeView; sl: TStringList);
var
  i: integer;
  curnod: TTreeNode;
  chunks: TStringList;
  parentNode: TTreeNode;
  level: integer;
begin
  tv.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    parentNode := nil;
    chunks := TStringList.Create;
    try
      for i := 0 to sl.Count - 1 do
      begin
        chunks.Delimiter := '.';
        chunks.StrictDelimiter := True;
        chunks.DelimitedText := sl[i];
 
        curnod := tv.Items.GetFirstNode;
        level := 0;
 
        while (curnod <> nil) and (level < chunks.Count) do
        begin
          if curnod.Text = chunks[level] then
          begin
            parentNode := curnod;
            curnod := curnod.GetFirstChild;
            Inc(level);
          end
          else
            curnod := curnod.GetNextSibling;
        end;
 
        while level < chunks.Count do
        begin
          parentNode := tv.Items.AddChild(parentNode, chunks[level]);
          Inc(level);
        end;
      end;
    finally
      chunks.Free;
    end;
  finally
    tv.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
 
procedure TForm1.OnCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  sl: TStringList;
begin
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  try
    sl.Duplicates := dupIgnore;
    sl.Add('Пост');
    sl.Add('Пост.Кладовая');
    sl.Add('Пост.Склад');
    sl.Add('Пост.Столовая');
    sl.Add('Пост.Столовая.Посудомоечная');
    sl.Add('Офис');
    sl.Add('Офис.Администрация');
    BuildTree(tvNodes, sl);
  finally
    sl.Free;
  end;
end;
```

У меня "офис" оказывается вложен в "посудомоечная". Вложенность может варьироваться:

```
Комната
Комната.Уборная
Комната.Уборная.Ванна1
Комната.Уборная.Ванна1.Ответвление
Комната.Уборная.Ванна2
Комната.Уборная.Ванна2.Ответвление
Комната.Уборная.Ванна2.Ответвление.Левое
Комната.Уборная.Ванна2.Ответвление.Правое
```

и т.д. Подскажите кодом, так как в коде легче разобраться, чем вычитывать между строк.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно переместить

```
parentNode := nil;
```

внутрь цикла `for`, иначе новая серия стартует с последнего записанного узла

Было:

```
try
    parentNode := nil;
    chunks := TStringList.Create;
    try
      for i := 0 to sl.Count - 1 do
      begin
        chunks.Delimiter := '.';
```

Надо:

```
try
    chunks := TStringList.Create;
    try
      for i := 0 to sl.Count - 1 do
      begin
        parentNode := nil;
        chunks.Delimiter := '.';
```

Comment: Куда именно переместить?

Comment: Например, перед `chunks.Delimiter := '.';`

Comment: Ничего не понял.

Comment: С больной башкой трудно соображать. Спасибо за подсказку.